# Best way to create user login in mobile app with azure

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Xamarin.forms mobile app with Azure. I have enabled Authentication/Authorization in Azure to protect the APIs in Backend.

What I need is that to ask user to login with Facebook or Google and get some information of the user such as name, email and... and then save this data in a  table as user information. I like to ask user just once for login and get the data and I don't need to keep the token provided by Facebook for example and refresh it always (which I red refreshing is not supported by Facebook), but also need to keep the user logged in and has access securely to Backend APIs. I am new in this and completely confused of using Azure AD, facebook and...

What is the best way to do that? I have followed [this](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/social/) tutorial and now am able to login with Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is Azure AD B2C (Business to Customer), which will provide facilities to allow your customers to create an account for your app, but also login with Facebook (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app)) or Google (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-goog-app)).

Since Azure AD B2C implements OAuth2, integrating it in a Xamarin.Forms app by means of Xamarin.Auth should be possible (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth)). Once you have acquired the OAuth2 token, you can include the token in the headers of your HTTP requests in the `Authorization` header with the `Bearer` type (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization))

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

On the server side you can then validate the token. I have not used Xamarin.Auth with [Json Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction/) (JWT), but maybe you'll be able to retrieve a JWT with Xamarin.Auth, which you'll be able to validate on yourself. Otherwise, if Xamarin.Auth is restricted to access tokens, you might have to contact the authentication server to verify the token. If the token is verified successfully, you can grant the user access, otherwise, answer them with a 401.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. Just have a couple of questions. I have a mobile app created in Azure and I need to get the current user in Backend and returns data with API depending on the user. Should I use B2C client flow or B2C server flow in this case?